# Celsius to Fahrenheit method doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, methods

I'm a novice in the computer devlopment world and I start with Python.

I try to create a Celsius - Fahrenheit (and vice-versa) converter using Tkinter. I create a method named "celsius_to_fahrenheit" and I define it like that :

```
def celsius_to_fahrenheit():
    n = celsius_entry.get()
    result = n * 9 / 5 + 32
    fahrenheit_entry.delete(0, END)
    fahrenheit_entry.insert(0, result)
```

The method is started by a button and when I push it, this error appeared :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[Me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Mes Documents/[Me]/Programmation/Python/Projets/ui/degree_farenheit.py", line 7, in celsius_to_fahrenheit
    result = n * 9 / 5 + 32
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'
```

I hope you can help me !

Comment: Have you tried changing: “n = celsius_entry.get()” to “n = float(celsius_entry.get())”?

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory you can't divide a string by an integer.

Answer (score 3):

The type of n is str. This needs to be converted into FLOAT before the calculation.

```
n = float(celsius_entry.get())
```

Comment: I try this but I have a new error :
```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\[Me]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "D:/Mes Documents/[Me]/Programmation/Python/Projets/ui/degree_farenheit.py", line 6, in celsius_to_fahrenheit
    n = float(celsius_entry.get())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Comment: @ItsWidee It is because you input nothing in the entry.

Comment: But how can I get what I put on the entry to use it

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full code of a working example:

```
from tkinter import *

degree_sign= u'\N{DEGREE SIGN}'

window = Tk()
window.title( '%cF -> %cC' % (degree_sign,degree_sign) )

entry = Entry( window )
entry2 = Entry( window )

def celsius_to_fahrenheit():
    n = float(entry.get())
    result = (n * (9/5)) + 32
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry2.insert(0, result)

def fahrenheit_to_celcius():
    n = float(entry2.get())
    result = (n -32) / (9/5)
    entry2.delete(0, END)
    entry.delete(0, END)
    entry.insert(0, result)

label = Label(window, text = 'Enter Celcius')
label.grid( row=1,column=1)
entry.grid( row=1,column=2 )
btn = Button( window , text = 'Convert to Farenheit' , command=celsius_to_fahrenheit )
btn.grid( row=1,column=3 )

label2 = Label(window, text = 'Enter Farenheit')
label2.grid( row=2,column=1)
entry2.grid( row=2,column=2 )
btn2 = Button( window , text = 'Convert to Celcius' , command=fahrenheit_to_celcius )
btn2.grid( row=2,column=3 )

window.mainloop()
```